# Why DBMS_XMLSCHEMA fails to validate a valid xs:dateTime?

Tags: oracle, validation, datetime, xsd, oracle11g

I'm going to validate and process XML provided by a third party. The XML conforms a standardized XML schema also provided by a third party.

For validation I use DBMS_XMLSCHEMA essentially this way:

```
-- pseudocode follows
declare
  xmldoc xmltype;
begin
  dbms_xmlschema.registerschema(schemaurl => name,
                                schemadoc => xmltype(schema),
                                local => true,
                                gentypes => false,
                                gentables => false
                                );
  xmldoc := xmltype(xml).createSchemaBasedXML(schema_name);
  xmldoc.schemavalidate;
end;
```

Validation seems to work except that I've run an issue with XML schema type `xs:dateTime` that is demonstrated below.

With XML schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="datetime-issue">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="time" type="xs:dateTime" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The validation of following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datetime-issue>
  <time>2011-06-15T16:58:23</time>
  <!-- Oracle doesn't like timezone ? -->
  <time>2011-06-15T16:58:23+02:00</time>
  <time>2011-06-16T09:55:01</time>
</datetime-issue>
```

Fails unexpectedly on the second time-element:

```
ORA-30992: error occurred at Xpath /datetime-issue/time[2]
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 354
```

AFAICS `2011-06-15T16:58:23+02:00` should be a valid XML schema [xs:dateTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) value and DBMS_XMLSCHEMA should not complain about that at all. Validation should also be independent on any database date format settings, right ?

So is this an Oracle quirk and if yes what are the workarounds ? Or should I configure Oracle and/or DBMS_XMLSCHEMA differently ? Or have I misinterpreted something or ...

I'm running Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0.

If it's worth of anything the example XML schema and data above validates correctly with [exchangerxml](http://code.google.com/p/exchangerxml/) that uses Xerces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can fix that by adding:

```
xdb:SQLType="TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE"
```

to the element in the XML schema. Though that may error on the non-timezone records...

Comment: When I added that [XML schema annotation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16659/xdb05sto.htm#i1030452) to the example the validation passed and there was no problems with elements missing the optional timezone. See also [Mapping XML Schema Data Types to SQL Data Types](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16659/xdb05sto.htm#i1030995). The problem is that the annotation is Oracle-specific and the XML schema is governed by third party. But how to overcome that restriction is worth of another debate.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a collection of relevant Oracle documentation that answers to my question. I accepted Phil's answer as I found the right section of documentation based on that.

From chapter [7 XML Schema Storage and Query: Basic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb05sto.htm) of [Oracle XML DB Developer's Guide 11g Release 2 (11.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/toc.htm):

> **Working with Time Zones**
>
> The following XML Schema data types allow for an optional time-zone indicator as part of their literal values.
>
> - `xsd:dateTime`
> - `xsd:time`
> - `xsd:date`
> - `xsd:gYear`
> - `xsd:gMonth`
> - `xsd:gDay`
> - `xsd:gYearMonth`
> - `xsd:gMonthDay`
>
> By default, XML schema registration maps `xsd:dateTime` and `xsd:time` to SQL data type `TIMESTAMP` and all the other data types to SQL data type `DATE`. SQL data types `TIMESTAMP` and `DATE` do not permit a time-zone indicator.
>
> If your application needs to work with time-zone indicators, then use attribute `SQLType` to specify the SQL data type as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. This ensures that values containing time-zone indicators can be stored and retrieved correctly. For example:
>
> ```
> <element name="dob" type="xsd:dateTime"
>       xdb:SQLType="TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE"/>
> <attribute name="endofquarter" type="xsd:gMonthDay"
>        xdb:SQLType="TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE"/>
> ```
>
> **Using Trailing Z to Indicate UTC Time Zone**
>
> XML Schema lets the time-zone component be specified as `Z`, to indicate UTC time zone. When a value with a trailing `Z` is stored in a SQL `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column, the time zone is actually stored as `+00:00`. Thus, the retrieved value contains the trailing `+00:00`, not the original `Z`. For example, if the value in the input XML document is `1973-02-12T13:44:32Z`, the output is `1973-02-12T13:44:32.000000+00:00`.

See also:

- [Oracle XML Schema Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb05sto.htm#ADXDB4514)
- [Mapping XML Schema Data Types to SQL Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb05sto.htm#ADXDB4527)
- [Table 7-9 Mapping XML Schema Date and Time Data Types to SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb05sto.htm#g1048807)