# How to redefine XML Schema type without redefine?

Tags: xml, oracle, xsd, oracle11g, redefine

This is a continuation question to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370035/why-dbms-xmlschema-fails-to-validate-a-valid-xsdatetime).

I have XML files and XML Schema provided by several different third parties. For some mysterious reasons Oracle requires an [Oracle specific annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370035/why-dbms-xmlschema-fails-to-validate-a-valid-xsdatetime/6370431#6370431) to be able to validate `xs:dateTime` with timezone information correctly.

After lengthy debates with [Google](http://www.google.com) I've found out that I could add Oracle required annotation non-intrusively (i.e without modifying the original XML Schema) by using [XML Schema redefine](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#Redefine).

XML Schema provided by third party is conseptually like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:simpleType name="ISODateTime">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime"/>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

And I could bring in the annotation this way with redefine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb">

  <xs:redefine schemaLocation="standard-schema.xsd">

    <xs:simpleType name="ISODateTime">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime" xdb:SQLType="TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE"/>
    </xs:simpleType>

  </xs:redefine>

</xs:schema>
```

Unfortunately according to [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb01int.htm#ADXDB3973) redefine is the single only XML Schema feature not supported by Oracle XML Database:

> **XML Schema Support**
>
> [...] Oracle XML DB supports all of the constructs defined by the XML Schema Recommendation, *except for `redefines`*.

(And my experiments support this statement.)

What options, if any, do I have to add the required `xdb:SQLType` annotation without modifying the original XML Schema ?

I'm running Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a simple XSLT transformation that adds the annotation, and run it whenever you need to generate the Oracle schema from the third-party schema.

Comment: But of course ! Why I didn't realized that myself - me stupid. In the past I've done quite a lot XSLT (not with Oracle, though) so no problems with that.